# How to mount BTRFS filesystem via CLI with switches defaults,noatime,commit=300,autodefrag

Tags: command-line, mount, fstab, btrfs

I have ubuntu on a 32GB USB2 flash stick that I carry around with me, it works fine booting on other machines I have to sometimes access.

Recently I added a volume that contains a lot of data (a 500GB disk) to my `fstab` so I can access it on one of the computers.

It is mounted with the options `defaults,noatime,commit=300,autodefrag` as I want these switches when mounting. If I boot from another computer, the drive is missing so I get dropped to a recovery console and have to comment out that line on the `fstab` and reboot.

I normally work around this by having 2 user accounts, one for "home" and one for "away", and mount the disk on autologin items for one account and not the other.

The command I use to mount for my "home" account is:

> udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda1

However this is missing the switches I want.
(`defaults,noatime,commit=300,autodefrag`)

Is there a way to parse these switches into the mount command via the CLI for a `btrfs` volume?

Kind regards
Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `udisksctl`, you can use the `--options` flag to specify what options to mount with. In your case, the command will be `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda1 --options "defaults,noatime,commit=300,autodefrag"` (the quotes might not be needed, but they are there just to be safe).

Note that only safe options will be passed through to the `mount` command; options such as `suid` and `dev` will be rejected. (See also the man page for `udisksctl`.)

That being said, you might want to modify your `/etc/fstab` file so that the 500GB file isn't considered "important" enough to stop booting. Using the `nofail` and/or `nobootwait` options might help here.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks it works and mounts correctly. Thanks for the tip on nofail for fstab, although in this instance I prefer the udiskctrl method. I was able to verify that this answer is 100% correct by using this command : `cat /proc/mounts` The relevant output was: `/dev/sda1 /media/aragorn/Internal btrfs rw,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,commit=300 0 0` Which was desired :)

Comment: After some testing, I found your other tip on using "nobootwait" in the options section of the FSTAB to be better, and have less restrictions. I am actually thinking this is a better option all around as it makes the entire setup simpler. Thanks for that tip :)